# The code that works for LinearRegressor returns AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'get' for DynamicRnnEstimator

Tags: tensorflow

In the beginning, I need to say that I am using TF v 1.1.

The code:

```
import random
import tensorflow as tf

xData = []
yData = []
for _ in range(10000):
    x = random.random()
    xData.append(x)
    y = 2 * x
    yData.append(y)


xc = tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column("")
estimator = tf.contrib.learn.DynamicRnnEstimator(problem_type = constants.ProblemType.LINEAR_REGRESSION,
                                                 prediction_type = PredictionType.SINGLE_VALUE,
                                                 sequence_feature_columns = [xc],
                                                 context_feature_columns = None,
                                                 num_units = 5,
                                                 cell_type = 'lstm', 
                                                 optimizer = 'SGD',
                                                 learning_rate = '0.1')

def get_train_inputs():
  x = tf.constant(xData)
  y = tf.constant(yData)

  return x, y

estimator.fit(input_fn=get_train_inputs, steps=TRAINING_STEPS)
```

I got:

> AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'get'

here.
The same code works for LinearRegressor instead of DynamicRnnEstimator.

> WARNING:tensorflow:From
>   E:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\learn\python\learn\estimators\dynamic_rnn_estimator.py:724:
>   regression_target (from
>   tensorflow.contrib.layers.python.layers.target_column) is deprecated
>   and will be removed after 2016-11-12. Instructions for updating: This
>   file will be removed after the deprecation date.Please switch to
>   third_party/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/head.py
>   WARNING:tensorflow:Using temporary folder as model directory:
>   C:\Users\pavel\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpzy68t_iw
>
> Blockquote
>
> **Traceback** (most recent
>    call last):  File
>    "C:/Users/pavel/PycharmProjects/rnnEstimator/main.py", line 31, in 
>    estimator.fit(input_fn=get_train_inputs, steps=1000)
>
> File
>    "E:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\deprecation.py",
>    line 281, in new_func return func(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>    "E:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\learn\python\learn\estimators\estimator.py",
>    line 430, in fit loss = self._train_model(input_fn=input_fn,
>    hooks=hooks)
>
> File
>    "E:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\learn\python\learn\estimators\estimator.py",
>    line 927, in _train_model model_fn_ops = self._get_train_ops(features,
>    labels)
>
> File
>    "E:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\learn\python\learn\estimators\estimator.py",
>    line 1132, in _get_train_ops return self._call_model_fn(features,
>    labels, model_fn_lib.ModeKeys.TRAIN)
>
> File
>    "E:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\learn\python\learn\estimators\estimator.py",
>    line 1103, in _call_model_fn model_fn_results =
>    self._model_fn(features, labels, **kwargs)
>
> File
>    "E:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\learn\python\learn\estimators\dynamic_rnn_estimator.py",
>    line 516, in _dynamic_rnn_model_fn sequence_length =
>    features.get(sequence_length_key) AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has
>    no attribute 'get'

Update:
 [Issue in TF repo's](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8842)

Comment: Could you include a stack trace in your question?

Comment: I have added. Also, I need to say that I have created Issue in TF repo's https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8842.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
BATCH_SIZE = 32
SEQUENCE_LENGTH = 16


xc = tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column("")
estimator = tf.contrib.learn.DynamicRnnEstimator(problem_type = constants.ProblemType.LINEAR_REGRESSION,
                                                 prediction_type = PredictionType.SINGLE_VALUE,
                                                 sequence_feature_columns = [xc],
                                                 context_feature_columns = None,
                                                 num_units = 5,
                                                 cell_type = 'lstm', 
                                                 optimizer = 'SGD',
                                                 learning_rate = 0.1)

def get_train_inputs():
  x = tf.random_uniform([BATCH_SIZE, SEQUENCE_LENGTH])
  y = tf.reduce_mean(x, axis=1)
  x = tf.expand_dims(x, axis=2)
  return {"": x}, y

estimator.fit(input_fn=get_train_inputs, steps=1000)
```